# Multiple queries in pagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I pass a few query strings to filter the result in paged list, but one query is overriding another, how to make a multiple filter in pagedList?

Here's my code:

```
string _dataIni = null;
string _dataFim = null;

IPagedList ocorrencias = null;

if(codOccu > 0)
{
    ocorrencias = db.CRM_OCORRENCIAS.Where(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA == codOccu)
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA)
              .ToPagedList(pagina, 40);
}

if (nomeEmp.Length > 0)
{
    ocorrencias = db.CRM_OCORRENCIAS.Where(o => o.CLIENTES.NOMEFAN.Contains(nomeEmp) || o.CLIENTES.NOMERAZAO.Contains(nomeEmp))
               .OrderByDescending(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA)
               .ToPagedList(pagina, 40);
}

if(dtAbert != null && dtFinal != null)
{
    ocorrencias = db.CRM_OCORRENCIAS.Where(o => o.DTABERTURA >= dtAbert && o.DTABERTURA <= dtFinal)
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA)
              .ToPagedList(pagina, 40);
                _dataIni = Convert.ToDateTime(dtAbert).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                _dataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(dtFinal).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}

//   
if (codOccu == 0 && nomeEmp == "" && dtAbert == null && dtFinal == null)
                ocorrencias = db.CRM_OCORRENCIAS
               .OrderByDescending(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA)
               .ToPagedList(pagina, 40);


ViewBag.DataIni = _dataIni;
ViewBag.DataFim = _dataFim;
ViewBag.Empresas = nomeEmp;

return View(ocorrencias);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the above post and looking foward in the microsoft tutorials i manage to find this tutorial: [sorting, filtering and paging with entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
and my solution end up like this:

```
var ocorrencias = from s in db.CRM_OCORRENCIAS
                   select s;

    if(codOccu > 0)
    {
        ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA == codOccu);
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeEmp))
    {
        ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(o => o.CLIENTES.NOMEFAN.Contains(nomeEmp) || o.CLIENTES.NOMERAZAO.Contains(nomeEmp));
    }
    if (dtAbert != null && dtFinal != null)
    {
        ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(o => o.DTABERTURA >= dtAbert && o.DTABERTURA <= dtFinal);
        _dataIni = Convert.ToDateTime(dtAbert).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        _dataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(dtFinal).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

    return View(ocorrencias.ToPagedList(pagina, 40));
```

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the queries are getting overwritten. You can append multiple where clauses. I have not compiled it but try this

```
if (codOccu > 0)
            {
                ocorrencias = db.CRM_OCORRENCIAS.Where(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA == codOccu)
                          .OrderByDescending(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA);
            }

            if (nomeEmp.Length > 0)
            {
                ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(o => o.CLIENTES.NOMEFAN.Contains(nomeEmp) || o.CLIENTES.NOMERAZAO.Contains(nomeEmp))
                           .OrderByDescending(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA);
            }

            if (dtAbert != null && dtFinal != null)
            {
                ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(o => o.DTABERTURA >= dtAbert && o.DTABERTURA <= dtFinal)
                          .OrderByDescending(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA);
                _dataIni = Convert.ToDateTime(dtAbert).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                _dataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(dtFinal).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }

            //   
            if (codOccu == 0 && nomeEmp == "" && dtAbert == null && dtFinal == null)
                ocorrencias = db.CRM_OCORRENCIAS;

            return return View(ocorrencias.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID_OCORRENCIA).ToPagedList(pagina, 40));
```

Comment: thanks, has some errors because it was not compiled, but it managed to clear my mind!!